# problem to save image in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can I save an image, I put a good image of type NSString So the question is:
is that you can Recordable jsut URL then displays image from this url

```
  NSString *PathImage =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
```

is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are asking if there is another way to store an image?  If so, the following solution should work.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);  //or UIImageJPGRepresentation(myImage);
```

Then when you want to call your image back, simply use

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

If you need to store it as a string, you can convert the data to a string using the following

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: how can I know the image type (jpg, png)

Comment: I don't believe the image type necessarily matters.  It's just a preference as to which you'd like to save to.  Most people seem to use png, though it's up to you